# Differentiability of $f(x,y)=\frac{\sin^4(x)\sin^4(y)}{x^2+y^2}$ extended by $f(0,0)=0$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

$f:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}, (x,y)\mapsto \begin{cases} \frac{\sin^4(x)\sin^4(y)}{x^2+y^2} &\text{if $(x,y) \neq (0,0)$ }\\0&\text{if $ (x,y)=(0,0)$}\end{cases}$

(i) Show that $f$ is differentiable  on its domain of definition and calculate $f'(0,0)$

(ii) Determine the Gradient in $P=(\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2})$

(iii) Find a direction $\vec {v}$, whose Directional derivative $\frac{\partial f}{\partial \vec {v} }  $ in $P$ is $0$

For (i) my idea was, to show that its partial derivative is continuous:

$f'(x,y) = \frac{2 \sin^3(x) \cos^4(y) (2 (x^2+y^2) \cos(x)-x \sin(x))}{(x^2+y^2)^2} \approx \frac{2 x^3 y^4 (2 (x^2+y^2) x-x^2)}{(x^2+y^2)^2} $ for small $x$ and $y$ is this correct? How to go on?

To (iii)

$ \langle \nabla f (\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}), \vec {v} \rangle = \langle \begin {pmatrix} -\frac{\pi}{2} \\ -\frac{\pi}{2} \end{pmatrix}, \begin {pmatrix} v_1 \\ v_2 \end{pmatrix} \rangle = -\frac{\pi}{2}(v_1+v_2)=0 \Rightarrow v_1=v_2$ So $\vec {v}=(1,1)^T$ would be a solution. Is this correct?

Comment: In (i): "...and f'$(0,0)$" what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

about part 1. Find df/dx in (0,0) using the limits-definition. Actually using L'Hoital rule you can see that this derivative is 0 regardless of the value of y. For df/dy (0,0) is the same. 
about part 2. Find the partial derivatives as a functions of x and y and find the functional values in x=Pi/2, and y=Pi/2
about part 3. consider cosW df/dx(Pi/2,Pi/2) + sinW df/dy(Pi/2, Pi/2) = 0 and find value for W.

Comment: For part 1, the existence of the partial derivatives doesn't necessarily imply differentiability.

Comment: Why is it allowed, to disregard $y$ and just consider $x$ using L'Hôpital's rule?

Comment: Take a look at the limit lim x->0 (f(x,y)-f(0,y))/(x-0) and consider y is a constant ...

Comment: But this only shows partial derivation? It's still necessary to show, that its continuous

Comment: It is true that the existence of the partial derivatives doesn't necessarily imply differentiability. But as soon as these partial derivatives are well defined and continuous in every neighbourhood of a given point, this implies differentiability. Consider the following example: f(x,y)={y^2/(x+y) if (x,y)=/= (0,0) and 0 if (x,y)=(0,0)}. Consider x->+0. Now df/dy = 1 - 1/(1+y/x)^2 and if y->-0 as -x then it's obvious that df/dy is not continuos in all neighbourhoods of (0,0). Therafore the function is not differentiable.

Comment: How to see that the  partial derivation is well defined? For me it's "$\frac{0}{0}$"

Comment: Let's get back to your example. Like you well mentioned before for very small values of x and y df/dx (df/dy is symmetric) is close to y^4(4x^3(x^2+y^2)-2x^5)/(x^2+y^2)^2=(2x^5y^4+4x^3y^6)/(x^2+y^2)^2=(2x^5+4x^3y^2)/((x/y)^2+1)^2. Now however x->0 and y->0 the denominator of this expression ((x/y)^2+1)^2 will never reach 0...

Comment: about part 3: is my solution above also correct?

Comment: Well, as soon as df/dx (Pi/2, Pi/2) = df/dy (Pi/2, Pi/2) = Z you can assume that CosW * Z + SinW * Z = 0 or otherwise Cos W + Sin W = Sqrt(2) * Cos (W - Pi/4) = 0 or W = 3Pi/4 + 2kPi. Therafore the direction is (Cos W, Sin W) = (-Sqrt(2)/2, Sqrt(2)/2)...